# How do I undo Ctrl+Alt+Backspace?

Tags: graphics, wubi

I'm installing Ubuntu from wubi and I pressed that and it went to a full screen cmd prompt looking thing and I think the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> did it.

Comment: Did it happen during installation?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> kills the GUI. You can try to restart it by restarting the corresponding daemon manually or just reboot.